# Can you set the DefaultItemOpen property of a Library via CSOM?

Tags: document-library

In a document library under advanced settings, you have a setting around "Opening Documents in the Browser" where it can be:

- Open in the client application
- Open in the browser
- Use the server default

I see that you can set the [DefaultItemOpen property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.defaultitemopen.aspx) on the document library with the SharePoint server-side API, but I want do this client-side via **CSOM**.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say this isn't possible with CSOM, but would love to be proven wrong.  I have looked into the list property bag hoping that it would provide clues.  It does have several properties, but none change when I manually change the setting.  Here is the PowerShell CSOM code I used to get the list properties:

```
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
$ctx.Load($list)  # Not sure if this is needed
$props = $list.RootFolder.Properties
$ctx.Load($props)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$props.FieldValues
```

That last statement shows all of the field values (I modified a few to protect the innocent):

```
Key                          Value
---                          -----
vti_hassubdirs               true
vti_listbasetype             1
vti_listrequirecheckout      true
vti_replid                   rid:{45DB8E26-BBB0-4490-87B9-F757C939B0AF}
vti_rtag                     rt:45DB8E26-BBB0-4490-87B9-F757C939B0AF@00000000000
vti_isbrowsable              true
vti_listservertemplate       101
vti_modifiedby               i:0#.w|<domain>\<user>
vti_parentid                 {8E643847-1D92-4306-A3F3-0AF68E8A73DD}
vti_listenableminorversions  true
vti_level                    1
vti_isscriptable             false
vti_isexecutable             false
vti_HasUpdatedTitle          1
vti_listenablemoderation     false
vti_listenableversioning     true
vti_foldersubfolderitemcount 1
vti_listtitle                <list title>
vti_metainfoversion          6
IsAttachmentLibrary          1
vti_docstoretype             1
vti_folderitemcount          1
vti_timelastmodified         10/12/2016 4:02:15 PM
vti_nexttolasttimemodified   10/12/2016 3:57:21 PM
vti_candeleteversion         true
vti_dirlateststamp           10/12/2016 4:01:16 PM
vti_listname                 {E3EFFBEB-8B16-41E6-BB66-7DA670135DC7}
vti_etag                     "{45DB8E26-BBB0-4490-87B9-F757C939B0AF},0"
vti_timecreated              10/7/2016 2:33:27 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, some properties are simply not available through CSOM.

As time goes by, they are being added (`RequestAccessEmail` is supported since 16.1.4727.1200).

However, for us on-premise people, specially 2013, I think it is very unlikely that any of these are getting support.

e.g.

[SPList.DefaultItemOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.defaultitemopen.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[SPList.NavigateForFormsPages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.navigateforformspages.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[SPWeb.RequestAccessEmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.requestaccessemail.aspx)

[SPListItem.SystemUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: You are correct. However, the systemupdate property was added in the august 2016 csom update. Check - https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-august-2016-updated

Comment: great news! at least for those who are lucky enough to be able to use it :)